# Train timeseries model in R and predict purely on out-of-sample data

Tags: r, time-series, predictive-models

I have two data files "train.txt' and 'test.txt' with single columns of data.
I want to learn a model only on training-data and generate an output on test-data. I can't seem to find a way to do that. Most `predict` invocations seem to be just starting from the end of training data. I have always been c++ heavy, and am just learning R.
I tried the `forecast` package in R.

```
train_data_ <- read.table ('train.txt');
train_data_ <- as.matrix ( train_data_ );

test_data_ <- read.table ('test.txt');
test_data_ <- as.matrix ( test_data_ );

fit_train_ <- ets(ts(train_data_));
fit_test_ <- ets(ts(test_data_),model=fit_train_);
onestep <-fitted ( fit_test_ );
fit_test10_ <- ets(ts (test_data_[1:10], model=fit_train_);
onestep10 <-fitted ( fit_test10_ );
head (onestep10); # print 10 lines
head (onestep); # prints 10 lines
# These are different.
```

This fails my goal of predicting the next step in test data in a way that the future testing data does not affect the prediction.
Just to explain what I mean by not looking into the future for prediction this link might help : [Problem Description](http://www.circulumvite.com/home/trading-dataset-question-and-leaderboard)